# Error: "The biometric unit could not be configured" after uninstall app using Windows Biometric Framework

Tags: c++, windows

I'm using the sample of Windows Biometric Framework on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1156801/FingerPrintf-A-small-library-for-quick-usage-of-th) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401634(v=vs.85).aspx) . First, everything is okay.
However, I try

1. unregister the biometric database (with commandline -uninstall as the sample)
2. register the biometric database again (with commandline -install)
3. rarely, not always, the app could install a new database again, but when I enrolled a fingerprint, it showed error message "The biometric unit could not be configured".

After a few days, I found that

1. After reinstall the database, the biometric database file could not be created in folder **C:\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase**
2. In registry, key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WbioSrvc\Databases** , the value **Filepath** is empty

With my case, I fixed it as bellow

1. After reinstall the database, I should restart Windows Biometric Service. the value **Filepath** changed from empty to correct name.
2. I tried to enroll. Failed. (Recommend: Although it failed, but I must enroll. Otherwise, step 3 wouldn't affect)
3. I should restart Windows Biometric Service again.
4. Done.

I don't know what happen with Windows Biometric Service?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I could understand your problem to some extent but not sure if c++ is the correct here.